# Grails war without tomcat plugin

Tags: tomcat, grails

When I build a grails 2.1.0 app with the tomcat 2.2.0 I get the following error on startup when I deploy on Tomcat 7:

> INFO: validateJarFile(/app/app/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.27.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
>   Dec 1, 2012 4:01:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener lifecycleEvent
>   SEVERE: Creation of the naming context failed: javax.naming.NamingException: Context is read only

and

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/PeriodicEventListener
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1128)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)

If I delete the tomcat-* jar files in the exploded war the app starts without a problem, or if I remove the tomcat plugin the app starts without a problem. 
Ideally I would like to build the app without the plugin but have for development purposes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, use the version of the Tomcat plugin that corresponds to the version of Grails you're using. The real problem though is that the plugin should only be available in development for the `run-app` and `run-war` scripts, but shouldn't end up in the WAR file created by the `war` script. If you have the plugin in application.properties, remove it (along with any other plugins that are there). This puts the plugin in `compile` scope and will lead to it being in the WAR file.

The correct way to use the plugin is to add a `build` scope dependency in the `plugins` section of `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
plugins {
   runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
   build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue in 2.1.1. No plugins are in my application.properties file and tomcat version is `$grailsVersion`. Bamboo handles my builds. Any idea why this is happening?